# How to use groovy XMLbuilder for attributes that have hyphens in the name

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using groovy and groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder to write a library that I will use to automate creating epub files. I'm writing a function that can be used to generate the container.xml file and I noticed that my IDE gives me an error when I try to use an attribute name that has a hyphen as opposed to when an attribute name doesn't have a hyphen.

```
def writer = new StringWriter();
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer);
def fullPath="full-path"
def mediaType="media-type"


def generateContainer()
{
    xml.xmlDeclaration()
    xml.container(version:'1.0', xmlns:'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container')
    {
        rootfiles
        {
            rootfile( this.fullPath:'OEBPS/content.opf',this.mediaType:'application/oebps-package+xml')
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use

```
full-path
```

I'm given an error. When I try to use

```
fullpath
```

it doesn't give me an error.

Why does this happen and how can I correct it? See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-epubtut/index.html?ca=drs-#download)

```
The value of full-path (in bold) is the only part of this file that will ever vary.
```

I want to be as accurate as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
def fullPath = "full-path"
def mediaType = "media-type"

xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration( version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8" )    
xml.container( version:'1.0', 
               xmlns:'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container' ) {

    rootfiles {
        rootfile( (fullPath) : 'OEBPS/content.opf', 
                  (mediaType): 'application/oebps-package+xml' )
    }
}

println writer
```

Make sure when you are referring to the variable `fullPath`, `(fullPath)` [braces] has to be used in order to use the value of the variable as attribute in the xml node.

Comment: Do you have to declare the mkp variable? I've seen it in examples, but when I try to use it in my code it gives me a null pointer error and crashes my program. When I simply use xml.xmlDeclaration() I don't actually get the xml declaration that I was expecting.

Comment: `mkp` is available by default and yes xmlDeclaration has to be on mkp. Refer MarkupBuilder's API for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can quote element and attribute names which have illegal identifier characters:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter();
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer);

xml.container(version:'1.0', xmlns:'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container') {
    "root-files" {
        "root-file"( "full-path" :'OEBPS/content.opf', 
                     "media-type" :'application/oebps-package+xml')
    }
}

def result =  writer.toString()

assert result.contains('full-path')
assert result.contains('media-type')
```